# how to send two or more params into my page using angularjs and servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angularjs, servlets

i have this example, get client list and new user and i want to send this params for my page.

```
function getDataFromServer($rootScope, $http){
 $http({
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
   url: '/ProjectAngular/mainServlet?action=listar'
 })
 .then(function success(response) {
    $rootScope.list = response.data[0];
    $rootScope.user = response.data[1];
 }, function error(response) {
    $rootScope.msg = response.data;
 });
```

servlet

```
List<User> listUsers= new UserDAO().findAll("User", "name");
String json = new Gson().toJson(listUsers);
User user = new User();
json += new Gson().toJson(user);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

I tried to concatenate the string json to have a similar element in a list in json

Comment: Don't concatenate the strings. Just add the new user to the Userlist and then parse it to json. And in the angular part there is only one "response.data" which contains all the user elements.

Comment: but how angular knows wich response.data is ? for example: 
clitentList = response.data;
newUser = response.data;

Comment: Response.data is the whole json response. Say something like {users: ["user":{"name":"hans"}]}. So all the users maybe in a list. response.data.users[0]. Do you know json structure at all?

Comment: more or less , I'm starting to study now